# Gitlab-ci running mysql docker and connect it with error ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (111)

Tags: mysql, docker, gitlab

I have see that are other post about these issue, but nothing for the specific case described below.
In my gitlab-ci test pipeline configuration I want to run a mysql docker, and connect to it directly from my runner. But I have difficult to connect to the database.
This is my gitlab-cy-yml test step:

```
services:
    - docker:dind
    - mysql:5.7
  script:
     - apt-get update && apt-get install -y git curl libmcrypt-dev default-mysql-client
     - mysql --version
     - sleep 20
     - docker login -u XXXXXXXX -p XXXXXXXXX
     - docker pull mysql:5.7
     - docker run --name ticketsDB -d -p 3304:3306 -it -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true mysql:5.7
     - mysql --protocol=tcp -u root -P 3304
     - create database ticketOnline;
     - use ticketOnline;
```

The error is during `mysql --protocol=tcp -u root -P 3304` connections:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (111)

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `docker:dind` service in you setup.

```
job:
  variables:
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "true"
    MYSQL_DATABASE: ticketsDB
  services:
    - mysql:5.7
  script:
     - apt-get update && apt-get install -y git curl libmcrypt-dev default-mysql-client
     - mysql --version
     - sleep 20
     - mysql --protocol=tcp -u root -P 3304 -h mysql -e "create database ticketOnline; use ticketOnline;"
     
     # -h to specify the host and -e to run a SQL query
```

Edit:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (111)

The error occurs because you are trying to connect to `localhost` instead of the mysql service. By default services have aliases that are created by GitLab by default. [Learn More in the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/#accessing-the-services).

If you need multiple mysql instance you can use multiple aliases like so:

```
services:
    - name: mysql:5.7
      alias: mysql-1
    - name: mysql:5.7
      alias: mysql-2
script: 
  - mysql mysql --protocol=tcp -u root -P 3304 -h mysql-1 # to connect to the first
  - mysql --protocol=tcp -u root -P 3304 -h mysql-2 # to connect to the second.
```

Comment: Thanks for the intervention, I tried to use the services not using the dockers manually, as you suggested, but I get this error: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' (111)...

Comment: Can you please provide the entire error log ?

Comment: In gitlab I see only this stack: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' (111)

Comment: Sorry I didn't pay attention, the port was wrong. You should use 3306 instead of 3304. I tried on GitLab.com with 3306 and it works.

Comment: That's mean that if I want to connects to database just created I can use 3306 port and wich ip address? localhost, 127.0.0.1 or other?

Comment: you should use 3306 as the port and the the service alias (in your case it is mysql) as the hostname

Comment: But consider if I want to connect via another protocol, for instance jdbc, wich parameters I can use? jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/ticketsDB ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243527/discussion-between-jonio-and-iduoad).

Comment: Yeah exactly! If you want to avoid confusion you can set the mysql hostname using an alias `services[0].alias: ticket-department-db` then use the same name in the connection string `jdbc:mysql://ticket-department-db:3306/ticketsDB`.